# What is ObjectiveC.gcno? Should it be included in source code repository?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, git, swift, version-control

I recently updated to Xcode 7. And just noticed this new file `ObjectiveC.gcno` in my project's root. My go-to source for gitignore files doesn't have it ignored. https://github.com/github/gitignore

It seems to be some sort of build artifact, but not sure. Should it be ignored?

My project has both Objective-C and Swift code together.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.GCNO` files are files which are generated by Xcode in order to manage code coverage information.

You can read about it here in the Apple docs: [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1514/_index.html).
There is no problem to either ignore them or push them to your repository.

Comment: Thanks! I'll ignore it. It just causes merge conflicts that people just don't care about!